# What is the eventCode for backspace?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the eventCode for backspace in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes use this to determine the keycodes for keys in javascript

Comment: It is 8. However, this isn't important. Important is why do you need this? If you are wanting to block it, mind you it is a very bad idea!

Comment: @abhitalks My money's on _trying to prevent back-navigation in forms when pressing_ `backspace`. I always found that an annoying, unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Event code for backspace is `8`

```
e.keyCode === 8
```

You can get more information from [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm)

Comment: `keyCode` is a number, not a string, i.e.: `e.keyCode === 8`

Answer (score 1):

The key code for backspace is 8.

```
document.onkeydown = KeyCheck; 
function KeyCheck()
{
   var KeyID = event.keyCode;
   switch(KeyID)
   {
      case 8:
      alert("backspace");
      break; 
      default:
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out with the following javascript which code is pressed:

```
$(window).bind("keydown",function(e){ 
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  console.log(code);
});
```

Comment: You do not need to use `e.keyCode` because jQuery will provide `e.which` in any case. See [event.which | jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).